# What's the best name to define the profit generated by someone in his company?

Tags: single-word-requests

Let's say you have two kind of people in a company: Workers and Sellers.

Workers **produce** things, the amount of things they create is measured by their **productivity**.

Sellers sell things for money, the amount of money they earn (for the company) is measure by their ______ ?

I was thinking about **profitability** but I'm not sure about it... What do you think?

Comment: you could use 'turnover' or 'sales revenue' for the actual money received; it wouldn't be the same as the 'profit' generated, but is that how you'd measure sales performance?

Comment: I've seen this metric described as *revenue impact*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several words that could be used.

["Top line"](http://www.quora.com/What-does-top-line-and-bottom-line-mean)

> Top Line is Gross Revenues; that is, every single dollar that comes in the door from the sale of your product or services.
>
> *www.quora.com*

"Sales figure(s)" also works in this context to mean "the amount of revenue generated by [actual] sales", though it can also refer to the number of sales made. for example "...the amount of money they earn is measured by their *sales figures*

"Sales [Revenue](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/revenue?s=t) (or just ['Revenue'](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/revenue?s=t)) can also be used:

> **noun**
>
> 3 - revenues, the collective items or amounts of income of a person, a state, etc.
>
> *www.dictionary.com*

For example "...the amount of money they earn for the company is measured by their sales revenues"